# Excel Range copied and transpose pasted to notepad.

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am an VB newbie and would like data which is currently rendered vertically in a range like this in excel:

1. London,
2. New York,
3. Tokyo,
4. Paris,
5. Moscow,

To be then copied and pasted into an .txt file horizontally

i.e. to this :London,New York,Tokyo,Paris,Moscow

and then saved.

I have written the following post google and SO and it works but the transpose element is not working and am a little confused (it still pastes it as a vertical list)

The list of names is approximately 3k currently so I don't want to do it in excel using TRANSPOSE(). But as I need the names for another program which needs it in this format.

London,New York,Tokyo,Paris,Moscow

Any direction appreciated. THANK YOU!

```
    Option Explicit 

    Sub ExportFile()

    Dim ff As Long, lRow As Long

    Const NameOfTheSheet As String = "Names"

    Const sTextTileDirectoryPath As String = "C:\Users\PCHome\Desktop\"

    ff = VBA.FreeFile

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NameOfTheSheet)
        lRow = .Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Open sTextTileDirectoryPath & .Range("J25").Value & ".txt" For Output Access Write As #ff
            Print #ff, Join(Evaluate(Replace(Replace("transpose(#AA2:AA@)", "#", "'" & NameOfTheSheet & "'!"), "@", lRow)), vbNewLine)
        Close #ff
    End With

    MsgBox "Text File Created", vbInformation

    End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't saving it as a csv file do the job?

Comment: @Kyoujin - I think the OP is trying to convert rows into columns on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it all in VBA with Application.Transpose.

```
Print #ff, Join(Application.Transpose(worksheets(NameOfTheSheet ).Range("AA2:AA" & lRow).Value), ",") & vbNewLine
```

Comment: Actually, as long as you are within that With ... End With block, the `worksheets(NameOfTheSheet )` part of that code line is redundant.